# Connection styles in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I was looking for connection styles [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/annotations_guide.html)

I got to know how to use them and successfully implemented in my project. But I didn't get what angleA , angleB, armA, armB, rad are being referred to.
Can someone explain the attributes of connection style?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?  My first thought of an answer is more-or-less identical to what you link to.

Comment: I didn't understand what is angle B in figure, what is angle B in the figure, what is armB. It would be helpful if you could make me identify them

Answer (score 0):

The docstrings for the different ConnectionStyle classes do a good job of explaining what geometric features these terms refer to. See e.g. [Angle](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/284f56aa09a97a3c2d1bf074514bff55c9fae153/lib/matplotlib/patches.py#L2754) or [Bar](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/284f56aa09a97a3c2d1bf074514bff55c9fae153/lib/matplotlib/patches.py#L2912).